# ¿Por qué no funciona el siguiente modal?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap, laravel-5

Este es mi modal:

```
<div class="modal fade modal-slide-in-right" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog"
 tabindex="-1" id="#comentario-{{$lib->lib_no}}" >
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('comenta.store', $lib->lib_no) }}">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Comentario</h4>
                @if(count($errors)>0)
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{$error}}</li>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </div>



                <div class="modal-body">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <label for="cmt_titulo">Título</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cmt_titulo" placeholder="Título...">

                    <br>
                        <label for="cmt_texto">Escribe tu comentario</label>
                    <br>
                        <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="cmt_texto" placeholder="Escribe tu comentario..."></textarea>
                    <br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmt_libro_no" value="{{$lib->lib_no}}">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
                    <button type="reset">Cancelar</button>
                </div>


        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

y aquí es donde al hacer click en el botón comentar debería aparecer:

```
@foreach($libros as $lib)

                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$lib->lib_titulo}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$lib->autor}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$lib->lib_fecha_creacion}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$lib->generoliterario}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$lib->generoartistico}}</td>
                                    <td>

                                        <a href="" data-target="#comentario-{{$lib->lib_no}}"  data-toggle="modal">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  data-norden="{{$lib->lib_no}}">Comentar</button></a>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn_add btn btn-primary" data-norden="{{$lib->id_libro}}">Ver Comentarios</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @include('cliente.comenta.comentario')
                            @endforeach
```

El modal se carga pues se ve al renderizar la página que se han creado los modales correspondientes, pero no se muestra cuando le doy al botón Comentar. He buscado en mil sitios y probado mil maneras pero no funciona, a veces no se cargaba y otras directamente ni se mostraba ni se cargaba.

Comment: ¿O sea que estás creando N modales? ¿es realmente necesario crear tantos? Mi solución sería crear solo uno...

Comment: Votando para cerrar como error tipográfico basado en la respuesta aceptada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el error esta en el id del modal, quitale el `#`

```
<div class="modal fade modal-slide-in-right" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="comentario-{{$lib->lib_no}}" >
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabía que un error tan pequeño podía dar tantos quebraderos de cabeza xD